# Why Hankel matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, convolution, hankel-matrices

Given a finite sequence $h = (h_0,h_1,h_2,\ldots,h_{2n-2})$, one can form the Hankel matrix

$$
H = \begin{bmatrix} h_0 & h_1 & h_2 & \cdots & h_{n-1} \\ h_1 & h_2 & h_3 & \cdots & h_n \\ h_2 & h_3 & h_4 & \cdots & h_{n+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
h_{n-1} & h_n & h_{n+1} & \cdots & h_{2n-2} \end{bmatrix}.
$$

I know by example that there are interesting things one can learn about the sequence by forming this matrix. For instance, one can use a rank-revealing ["Vandermonde decomposition"](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.35.1833&rep=rep1&type=pdf) this matrix to represent this sequence as a sum of exponentials

$$
h_j = \sum_{i=1}^k c_i z_i^j,
$$

I also know of natural examples of Hankel matrices that appear in applications (e.g., the [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix), the Gram matrix of the monomials $1,x,\ldots,x^{n-1}$ in some weighted $L^2$ inner product space, etc.)

Despite these examples, I still feel like I don't have an answer *in my bones* to the following question:

> Given a sequence $h$, why is it **natural** to form the Hankel matrix $H$? Phrased differently, in what way is it natural to identify a sequence $h$ with the **operator** $H$?

For highly related ways of converting a sequence to a matrix, I don't have these answers. If I rearrange $h$ into a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) $T$, the linear transformation $T$ represents convolution with $h$. If I arrange $h$ into a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) $C$, the linear transformation $C$ represents a circular convolution with $h$.

I don't have a similar understanding for $H$ as a linear transformation. Multiplication by $H$ is a convolution operation of sorts, but it is "backwards". One answer to my question might be why this "backwards" convolution operator is a natural operation, making it natural to move from $h$ to $H$.

Comment: I think it's most sensible to think of $H$ as an embedding of the sequence $(h_n)$ in a higher dimensional space. One way to frame this in terms of the operator $H$ is as follows: let $e:\{0,\dots,n-1\} \to \Bbb C^n$ be such that $e(0),\dots,e(n-1)$ is the standard basis. If $h:\{0,1,\dots,2n-2\}$ is a finite sequence, then $H\circ e:\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ is the embedding of this sequence in $\Bbb C^n$. Importantly, the "left kernel" of $H$ corresponds to recurrences satisfied by the sequence $(h_n)$.

Comment: Well written question. A way to understand a liitle intuitively (infinite...) Hankel matrices is through the famous "**moment problem**" ; see for example [here](http://www.london-analysis-seminar.org.uk/Hankel2017/Berg.pdf)

Comment: Hankel matrices and their determinants are associated with the so called Hamburger moment problem. [see](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_moment_problem)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\L{L^2(\mathbb S^1)}
\newcommand\M{\mathscr M_f}
\newcommand\T{\mathscr T_f}
\newcommand\Ha{\mathscr H_f}
\newcommand\H{H^2}
\newcommand\Hp{(\H)^\perp}$

I may be mistaken but I believe the first class of Hankel matrices considered by the German mathematician Hermann Hankel is
inspired by the Hankel operators which are actually defined  on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space.  Infinite Hankel
matrices have the form $A=(a_{n,m})_{n, m=0}^\infty $, where  $a_{n, m}$ is a function of $n+m$.

One way to introduce Hankel matrices in a very natural way is to consider the multiplication operators on
$\L $ associated to a measurable, bounded, complex valued function $f$ on the unit circle.  That is, for
every $\xi $ in $\L $ we let
$$
  \M (\xi )|_z = f(z)\xi (z), \quad \forall z\in  \mathbb S^1,
  $$
so that $\M $ becomes a bounded operator on $\L $.

The matrix of $\M $ relative to the "Fourier basis" $\{e_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb Z}}$ of $\L $ (where each $e_n$ is defined by   $e_n(z)=z^n$) is
given by
$$
  a_{n,m}=\big \langle \M (e_m),e_n\big \rangle  =
  \int_{\mathbb S^1} f(z)z^mz^{-n}\, dz =
  \int_{\mathbb S^1} f(z)z^{-(n-m)}\, dz =
  \widehat f(n-m).
  $$
Notice that the entries of this matrix depend on $n-m$, rather than $n+m$ as in the Hankel matrix case.

Well, matrices indexed by ${\mathbb Z}\times {\mathbb Z}$, whose entries $a_{n, m}$ depend on $n-m$, as above,  are called Laurent matrices.

It
is a well known result that for any Laurent matrix $A=(a_{n,m})_{n, m\in {\mathbb Z}}$
corresponding to a bounded operator on $\L $, there is a measurable, bounded function $f$ such that
$$
  a_{n,m}=\widehat f(n-m).\qquad\qquad (*)
  $$

Another important class of operators is formed by the Toepliz operators $\T $, also associated to measurable, bounded functions
$f$, but this time $\T $ acts on the Hardy space $\H$, namely the subspace of $\L $ defined
by
$$
  \H = \overline{\text{span}}\{e_n:n\geq 0\}.
  $$
Denoting by  $P$ the orthogonal projection from $\L$ to $\H$, one   may define $\T $ as
$$
  \T =P\M |_{\H}.
  $$
The matrix of $\T $ is also given by the expression $(*)$, except that now the indices $n$ and $m$ range in ${\mathbb N}$,
rather then ${\mathbb Z}$.  One may therefore see a Toepliz matrix as the bottom right corner of a Laurent matrix (as long as
the rows are labled with indices increasing downwards).

An important result states that any matrix indexed by ${\mathbb N}\times {\mathbb N}$, whose entries $a_{n, m}$ depend on $n-m$, and which
corresponds to a bounded operator on $\H$ is necessarily given by $(*)$, where $f$ is a measurable, bounded function.

Yet another operator "embedded" in the multiplication operator $\M $ is the so called Hankel operator
$$
  \Ha:\Hp \to \H
  $$
given by $\Ha=P\M |_{\Hp}$.  Its matrix is again given by $(*)$, with the difference that its columns are now
indexed by the negative integers, corresponding to the basis
$$
  \{e_n:n<0\}
  $$
of its domain $\Hp$, while the rows are indexed by the natural numbers.

The matrix of a Hankel operator is therefore the bottom left corner of the corresponding Laurent matrix.

Contrary to the Laurent and Toepliz cases, a Hankel operator is not an operator from a Hilbert space to itself, as its
domain is perpendicular to its range.  Nevertheless, $\H$ is obviously isomorphic to $\Hp $, e.g. by the map
sending each $e_m$ to $e_{-m-1}$, for every  $m<0$.  Identifying $\H $ and  $\Hp$ via this isomorphism $\Ha$ becomes
an operator on $\H$, whose matrix is now indexed by ${\mathbb N}\times {\mathbb N}$, and each entry, suitably modified by the change of
coordinates $m\rightarrow -m-1$, becomes
$$
  b_{n,m}= a_{n, -m-1} = \widehat f(n+m+1). \qquad\qquad (\dagger)
  $$

We therefore finally arrive at what I believe is the most natural introduction of the notion of Hankel matrices!

Observe that, while the entries of Laurent and Toepliz matrices include (with lots of repetitions) all of the Fourier
coefficients of the associated measurable function $f$, the same is no longer true with respect to $(\dagger)$, as only
positively indexed Fourier coefficients are used.  This makes the characterization of bounded Hankel matrices a bit
trickier but still formally the same as before: Nehari's Theorem asserts that a Hankel matrix represents a bounded
operator on $\H$ if and only if there exists a measurable bounded function $f$ such that $(\dagger)$ holds.

Nonzero Laurent and Toepliz operators are never compact, but of course Hankel operators can be.  E.g., if $f$ is a
trigonometrical polynomial, it is clear that $\Ha$ is a finite rank operator.

Compact Hankel operators were
characterized by  Hartmann in a result that states that a Hankel matrix represents a compact
operator on $\H$ if and only if there exists a **continuous** function $f$ such that $(\dagger)$ holds.

I may be admonished by Stack Exchange users for expressing my personal opinion but nevertheless let me say that  the
process of arbitrarily modifying  a linear transformation between two different Hilbert spaces (for which no spectral theory is
meaningful) into an operator from a Hilbert space into itself, must have raised the wrath of the gods leading to the
terrible behaviour of the spectral properties of Hankel matrices!

Comment: Very interesting and deep answer, in particular your last paragraph about the wrath of the gods... for the fact that the smallest eigenvalue of a Hankel matrix (in particular when linked to the moments problem) is rapidly very small. See for example https://doc.global-sci.org/uploads/Issue/CiCP/v1n18/118_104.pdf?code=auaddT33pDGUNql7Dw%2B9nQ%3D%3D

Comment: @Jean, thanks very much for your comment.  Not being a specialist
on numerical analysis, I knew only superficially about the difficulties
of computing the eigenvalues of Hankel matrices.  The paper you
suggested does indeed make this point a lot clearer!

Comment: Thank you for this very deep answer. I feel like this answer raises another question: In what sense is $\mathscr{H}_f$ a "natural" operator? Why would I think to restrict the multiplication operator in this way and what do I learn about $f$ by doing so?